# NameError: global name 'WTI' is not defined

Tags: python, error-handling

As part of my log in GUI, once the correct details are entered, the user goes through to the homescreen page.

```
def login():
     content = nameentry.get()
     content1 = IDentry.get()
     if content == "1" and content1 == "1":
         root.destroy(), execfile("Homescreenscroll - Copy3.1.py")
```

However, when the Homescreenscroll - Copy3.1.py is opened and runs, it says

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\Py\lib\threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
>
> self.run()
>
> File "C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\Py\lib\threading.py", line 483,
>    in run
>
> self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
>
> File "Homescreenscroll - Copy3.1.py", line 5862, in trick
>
> ```
> WTI['text'] = row[0]
> ```
>
> NameError: global name 'WTI' is not defined

Even though it is clearly defined in the 'Homescreenscroll - Copy3.1.py' file

It is part of this thread in the 'Homescreenscroll - Copy3.1.py' file:

```
WTI = Label(text = "")

def trick(threadName, sleepTime):
    while 1 < 2:
    db=MySQLdb.connect(host = "xxx",
                    user = "xxx",
                    passwd = "xxx",
                    db = "test")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""xxxx""", (xxxxx)) 
    cursor.execute("""xxxx""", (xxxx))
    db.commit()
    row=cursor.fetchone()
    WTI['text'] = row[0]


try:
    t = threading.Thread(target=trick, args=("Trick running", 5))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
except: Exception,
print "start up"
```

Comment: your `login` function and `try` section look empty here, please fix the indentation.

Comment: I guessed `Label` it is a `Tkinter` object. please add this information. in addition, try to add the line `global WTI` in the beginning of `trick` function

Answer (score 0):

Define WTI.
Put some text in the definition, instead of nothing.

Comment: it is initially meant to open empty and the Function 'trick' then fills it in.

Comment: Where does the row[0]  come from?

Comment: row[0] is from the cursor.execute, row=cursor.fetchone()

Comment: What kind of output is row[0] ?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to import the module. That seemed to have done it for me.

So, from the login GUI I have put:

```
def login():
content = nameentry.get()
content1 = IDentry.get()
if content == "1" and content1 == "1":
    root.destroy()
    from HomescreenscrollCopy31 import FullScreenApp
```

The only issue now is that within that module is the thread called 'Trick' which is not running when called through the login way. It only works when I run the actual HomescreenscrollCopy31.py version itself!

HomescreenscrollCopy31.py looks likes this:

```
class FullScreenApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)            
    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom

    def trick(threadName, sleepTime):
        while 1 < 2:
            ....
    try:
        t = threading.Thread(target=trick, args=("Trick running", 5))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    except: Exception,
    print "start up"
```

When opened via the login screen, the shell only prints the "start up" and never the "Trick running"

Why is this?